# Scala abstract method param question, List of T

Tags: scala, methods, abstract

I have a helper method:

```
def controlStructure[T <: SomeObject](exceptions: Class[_]*)(body: => T) = { 
    try { 
        val tempObject = body 
        tempObject.callSomeMethod 
        Some(tempObject) 
    } catch { 
        case e if (exceptions.contains(e.getClass)) => None 
    } 
}
```

called with:

```
controlStructure[MySomeObject](classOf[Exception]) { getMySomeObjectSomehow }
```

the main point of which is to call the 'callSomeMethod' on the entity passed in (for example loaded from ORM), it incidentally wraps things up in exception handling too.

I would now like to add a new method which does the same thing but for a collection (java.util.List) of T.

I am unsure of the syntax, and structures to work with a collection of T in the method signature, and abstract type param definitions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question to use code blocks for your code samples. It's very difficult to read as-is.

Answer (score 1):

With a scala list,  you are wanting something like this (I think):

```
  def controlStructure[T <: SomeObject](exceptions: Class[_]*)(body: => List[T]) = {
    try {
      val tempObject = body
      tempObject.foreach { _.callSomeMethod() }
      Some(tempObject)
    }
    catch {
      case e if (exceptions.contains(e.getClass)) => None
    } 
  }
```

I haven't worked with Java lists in scala, so I'm guessing you could do it with java.util.List like this:

```
  def controlStructure[T <: SomeObject](exceptions: Class[_]*)(body: => java.util.List[T]) = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    try {
      val tempObject = body
      tempObject foreach { _.callSomeMethod() }
      Some(tempObject)
    }
    catch {
      case e if (exceptions.contains(e.getClass)) => None
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  

Sorry I forgot to mention, I am using Scala 2.8.0-Beta1-RC2, so I assumed I could just automatically call 'foreach' on tempObject without the need for the .toArray stuff by importing 'scala.collection.JavaConversions._', however it is telling me

found   : java.lang.Object
required:java.util.List[MySomeObject]

Any ideas?

Comment: Edited to use JavaConversions and it works as shown for me (using Scala 2.8.0.r19890).  Can you confirm your code matches?

Comment: Hi.  My JavaConversions import is at the top of the file, and I am passing a java.util.ArrayList[MySomeObject] with one item into the controlStructure construct.  The only other difference I can think of is that my SomeObject is part of my domain layer, and so inherits from various traits?

Answer (score 0):

There's no pass by name vararg in Scala. You have to pass a function if you want this. See [this ticket](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/237) of an enhancement request to this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Mitch.  It turns out the answer is in this case to specify the return type of the method, as java.util.List[T], as for once Scala is not using its magic type inference to sort everything out.